# Android TextView text background color

Tags: android, user-interface

How can I achieve such an effect with an Android TextView. It looks somehow like selected text and I couldn't find something similar in the API.

This is not a background color for the view, but a background color only for the text. You can see how it stops at line breaks and has a thin white line between text lines.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi Ole, have you solved this question? I would also need the same behaviour

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextView with background color and line spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939862/textview-with-background-color-and-line-spacing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see, there's no 'nice' way of doing this without overriding TextView and drawing custom paints on the view which includes the gap colour.

Even setting the `lineSpacingExtra` property only expands the background colour.

You could also potentially look into creating a custom `spannable` and use it like

```
Spannable str = new SpannableStringBuilder("How can I achieve such an effect with an Android TextView. It looks somehow like selected text and I couldn't find something similar in the API.");
str.setSpan(new NewSpannableClass(), 0, str.length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(str);
```

Where `NewSpannableClass` is the custom spannable.

Seeing as many people are lazy to look up how to make custom spannables, here's an example

```
public class CustomSpannable extends ClickableSpan
{
    @Override public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds)
    {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setUnderlineText(true);
    }
}
```

This example will underline the text. Use `TextPaint` to change the look of the spanned text.

Comment: Ya, you are true. lineSpacingExtra property only expands the background colour. any one got solution for this?

Comment: I would like to see the complete code, please.
The answer is accepted, but I don't get "NewSpannableClass"

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing that complete code too.

Comment: Hi.. i have used same code but it does not give me same result.

Comment: For bacground color I added this code inside updateDrawState: 
ds.bgColor = argb(120, 0, 0, 0);
Note that when I used color format like this: "#FFF5F19E" - the colors were wrong.

Answer (score 17):

```
<TextView
android:background="#0000FF"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Would define a `TextView` with a blue background and white text...is that what you need?

Answer (score 5):

I believe there's an easier, nicer way to go about achieving this: simply create a backgroundColorSpan and add it to a SpannableString. Something along those lines:

```
public static SpannableString buildBackgroundColorSpan(SpannableString spannableString,
                                                String text, String searchString, int color) {

    int indexOf = text.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchString.toUpperCase());

    try {
        spannableString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(color), indexOf,
                (indexOf + searchString.length()), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }


    return spannableString;
}
```

Where "spannableString" is the SpannableString object created and assumed to be initialised with "text"; "searchString" represents the piece of text you wish to "highlight" in your TextView, and "color" the background colour to which the "highlighted" text should be set.

```
String text = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps over the Lazy Dog";
String searchString = "brown";
int color = Color.parseColor("#FFF5F19E");

SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
spannableString = StringUtils.buildBackgroundColorSpan(spannableString, text, searchString, color);
```

I think this should suffice.

Thanks

Comment: It works, but instead of this:
int color = Color.parseColor("#FFF5F19E");
I use this:
int color = argb(120, 0, 0, 0);
(to make transparent black color, for example). When I tried to use color format like "#FFF5F19E" - the colors were wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use this example

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

for picking color use this link
http://html-color-codes.info/

> Red:#750A0A
>
> Blue:#002BFF
>
> Green:#33FF00
>
> White:#FFFFFF
>
> Black:#000000

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it from XML try the solution of the other people who just answered like:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#1bgtbgt"/>
```

If you want to do it from Activity Code you can change it dynamically like try with:

```
text.setBackgroundColor( int color);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below the `textview` in `.xml` file:

```
<TextView android:background="#0000FF">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the TextView length as `match_parent` assuming that it is nested within a parent value that spans the whole length of the screen, and your text will be the same length, but the box will increase to the whole length of the screen.

Answer (score -1):

Try Using this for text background color

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment_dis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Stack Overflow
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#3cabdc"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add another layout around the TextView and set its background to the colour you want

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/text" />

</LinearLayout>
```