# Android Setbackground Color For Custom Text View

Tags: android, textview

I m trying to set background color text view to length of the text in that text view , 
if I  use `textView.SetBackground()` then it will set background color to whole textview , i dont want this , I want backgorund color only for Text of that Textview... Thanks in advance...

Comment: What? are you saying that font color? What is background color of text?

Comment: please be more clear else we need to flag

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582900/android-textview-text-background-color i want something like this....Android TextView text background color

Answer (score 0):

Set the TextView's layout_width to wrap_content, then the background will only be as lasrge as the content.

Answer (score 0):

use SpannableString class

here is example

```
String btnText = btn.getText();
SpannableString spannableSummary = new SpannableString(btnText);
spannableSummary.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xff6083f0), 0, summary.length(), 0);

btn.setText(btnText);
```

Comment: Actualy this is working , but not working with Custom TextView

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
textView.setTextColor();
```

To set text colour for your text view.

Comment: Thanks ,but I want to set background color for text  Not Text Color

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String text = "This is <font color='blue'>blue</font>. This is <font color='red'>red</font>.";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```